# Django showing values of an annotated queryset without knowing the filed name

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I´m building a dashboard where you can cross data from a sales database.

For example, sales by seller, products by client, etc. I let the user choose both option 1 and option 2.

I get the form back to the view and annotate the model with those options:

```
if filter_opts.is_valid():
    option_1 = filter_opts.cleaned_data["option_1"]
    option_2 = filter_opts.cleaned_data["option_2"]
    results = ventas.values(option_2).annotate(Count(option_1, distinct=True))
```

The annotation works fine and if I just print the queryset in the template

```
{% for case in results %}
    {{ case }}
{% endfor %}
```

I can see it like:

```
{'cliente': '502 EMSUR', 'prod_nombre__count': 9}
```

Then in the template I want to show only the values. But I can´t tell forehand which would be the value name to do something like this:

```
{% for case in results %}
    {{ case.option_1 }}
    {{ case.option_2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

If I iterate over the result I can see the field name:

```
{% for case in results %}
    {% for item in case %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I show the values of that fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each `case` in `results` is a dictionary, you can use the property `.items` inside the template to iterate through its keys and values:

```
{% for case in results %}
    {% for item, value in case.items %}
        {{ item }} - {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks @bertucho, thought that only worked with Pandas dataframes. If I have more than one value per item, how can I show it?

Comment: If you mean that a `value` here could be a list of items, you could iterate it like `{% for x in value %}`. Is that what you mean?